# How to create a column of variable in R indicating before and after a specific date

Tags: r

For each county, I want to have a continuous date from `2020-01-01` to `2020-06-01`. Before the given date should be `"BO"`. after the date, it should be `"DO"`.

The sample data is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bHke6GxtzofXGpiG6IMwF2OkYCxFq8Hb/view?usp=sharing).

The desired output is like this

[image]

Comment: 1) You can provide your data in a reproducible format in your question itself instead of redirecting us to another site. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). 2) What do you mean by `Before the given date should be "BO". after the date, it should be "DO".` ? What is a given date? Which values do you want as "BO" and which one do you want as "DO" ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can do a simple if_else command with your cut date as condition. This works well if your date variable is formatted as date.

Using some of your data you linked and reading it in as a data frame `df` you can use:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(date_date   = as.Date(date_first, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
         OrderStatus = if_else(date_date > "2020-04-01", "BO", "DO"))
```

The if_else command is just an example. You can change this to the condition you need.